Show data from 2 table in laravel 11x
I can input data into 2 different tables, namely the question table and the answer table. But I have difficulty displaying the data according to each id_question. I have tried it but all the data in the answer table is displayed.
This is some example data for each Table.
question



Id
question




1
The correct answer is


2
How old is Ani?



answer



Id
id_question
answer




1
1
give


2
1
given


3
1
gave


4
1
gain


5
2
8 years old


6
2
9 years old


7
2
10 years old


8
2
11 years old



And this is my controller:
public function question Dashboard(){
     $questions = Question::with('answers')->get();
     $answers = Answer::with('questions')->get();
     return view('admin.questionDashboard', ([`questions`=>$questions, `answers`=>$answers]));
}


Where's the code that would handle "displaying the data according to each id_question"? As far as I see, you select all models from both tables, but don't connect them. Does that happen in your Blade template (which you haven't shared)?

Post your questionDashboard view, your Question model and your Answer model. This can probably be fixed in the view, but I think for the future we should make sure your relationships are correct on your models.

Note that following the Laravel naming conventions will make life a lot easier. Rename your "id_question"  to "question_id", and follow the documentation on Eloquent relationships. Laravel will do most of the work for you.

Just use relationships to make it easy.
public function question_dashboard(){
     $questions = Question::with('answers')->get();
     return view('admin.question.dashboard', (['questions'=>$questions]));
}

Question Model:
public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class, 'id_question');
}

Answer Model
public function question()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
}

Note:
Use related name for the column name like id_question => question_id.

There's no need to fetch the answers separately as the with() method eager-loads them already. Here's how you can adjust your controller:
Updated Controller:
public function questionDashboard() {
    $questions = Question::with('answers')->get();
    return view('admin.questionDashboard', ['questions' => $questions]);
}

Then make sure the Question and Answer models are set up with the proper relationships.
Question Model:
public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class, 'id_question');
}

Answer Model:
public function question()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Question::class, 'id_question');
}

Blade view:
You can loop through each question and its related answers like this:
@foreach ($questions as $question)
    <h3>{{ $question->question }}</h3>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($question->answers as $answer)
            <li>{{ $answer->answer }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach


Thank you very much sir, the problem is solved. it works fine.
